# Animating an InterpolationFunction and its integral

Tags: graphics3d, animation

I have a list of data that I interpolate (`Omega[t]`) and animate - it is working fine, but an `Integrate` over the `InterpolationFunction` (`Omega[t]`) and then animating it doesn't work.

Any suggestions ?

CODE:

```
data = {150, 148, 145, 144, 143, 80, -80, -81, -82, -83};
Omega = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 4]; 
Plot[Omega[t], {t, 1, 10}]

Animate[Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{-20, -20, -1.01}, {20, 20, -1}], 
                    GeometricTransformation[{Green, Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.15}}, 
                         {1.25, 0}], 
                         Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1/4],
                         Blue, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 1/4]}, 
                         RotationTransform[Omega[t], {0, 0, 1}]]},
               Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, PlotRange -> 3,  
               PlotRange -> 3],
     {t, 1, 10, 0.04}, AnimationRunning -> False, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

And my object spins, but after this

```
OmegaIntegrate = Evaluate@Integrate[Omega[t], t];
Plot[OmegaIntegrate, {t, 1, 10}]
```

and then

```
 Animate[Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{-20, -20, -1.01}, {20, 20, -1}], 
                GeometricTransformation[{Green, Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.15}}, {1.25, 0}], 
                     Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1/4], 
                     Blue, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 1/4]}, 
                RotationTransform[OmegaIntegrate[t], {0, 0, 1}]]}, 
           Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, PlotRange -> 3, 
           PlotRange -> 3],
      {t, 1, 10, 0.04}, AnimationRunning -> False, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: The link to your file doesn't work, also this is not the preferred way of sharing your code. You should include the code in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {150, 148, 145, 144, 143, 80, -80, -81, -82, -83};
omega = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 4]; 

omegaIntegrate := Integrate[omega[s], s]; 

Animate[Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{-20, -20, -1.01}, {20, 20, -1}], 
    GeometricTransformation[{Green, Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.15}}, {1.25, 0}], 
      Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1/4], Blue, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 1/4]}, 
     RotationTransform[omegaIntegrate, {0, 0, 1}]]}, Boxed -> False, 
   SphericalRegion -> True, PlotRange -> 3, PlotRange -> 3] /. s -> t, 
{t, 1, 10, 0.04}, AnimationRunning -> False, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Such a simple solution and I struggled with a few hours.THX.

Comment: @Mariusz, my pleasure. Thanks for the accept.